# Searchable Angular Tree for large tree possibly with KendoUI's TreeView

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm building a website using Angular JS as the presentation framework talking to a WebApi backend and need to render and tree control with a large amount of data (slightly under 1 MB). The tree needs to support check boxes and provide events when leafs or branches are selected. It is essential for the users that they can search for nodes in the tree by either the name of the node or a know ID associated with the node.

I've been looking at Telerik's Kendo UI however I have the following problems that I've not been able to resolve:

- When the tree has loadOnDemand set to false (which it has to be because of the data size) the find methods of the control do not work
- findByText only supports exact matching as far as I can tell (not an essential feature but certainly desirable)
- No obvious was to find the node based on the second Id

I'd be happy to offload some of the work to our WebApi backend but can't see how the Telerik control would support this. I'd appreciate help in resolving these issues or a recommendation for a performant alternative to Telerik's tree control

I attempted to create a sample snippet on Telerik's [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/) however the registration process is not working for me. I've created a small sample to demonstrate the problem but it appears to be runnable here too.

```js
 angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"]);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: [{
          id: 1,
          extenalId: "AA",
          text: "Item 1"
        }, {
          id: 2,
          extenalId: "BA",
          text: "Item 2",
          items: [{
            id: 21,
            extenalId: "BB",
            text: "SubItem 2.1"
          }, {
            id: 22,
            extenalId: "BC",
            text: "SubItem 2.2"
          }]
        }, {
          id: 3,
          extenalId: "CC",
          text: "Item 3"
        }]
      });

      $scope.itemTemplate = "<span title='{{dataItem.extenalId}}'>{{dataItem.text}}</span>";
      $scope.findNode = findNode;
      $scope.findById = findById;
      $scope.findByExternalId = findByExternalId;


      function findNode(item) {
        var treeView = $("#sTree").data("kendoTreeView");
        // TODO: How do we find SubItem 2.1 if the tree has not been expanded
        // TODO: How do we do a contains search

        var node = treeView.findByText($scope.search);
        if (node.length) {
          console.log("found");
          treeView.expandTo(treeView.dataItem(node));
          if (node[0].textContent === $scope.search)
            treeView.select(node);
        }
      }

      function findById() {
        var treeView = $("#sTree").data("kendoTreeView");
        //TODO: How do we find 22 if the tree has not been expanded
        var dataItem = treeView.dataSource.get($scope.searchId);
        var node = treeView.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
        if (node.length) {
          console.log("found by id");
          treeView.expandTo(treeView.dataItem(node));
          treeView.select(node);
        } else
          console.log("Not found by id");
      }

      function findByExternalId() {
        var treeView = $("#sTree").data("kendoTreeView");
        //TODO: How do we find BB
        var dataItem = treeView.dataSource.get($scope.searchId2);
        var node = treeView.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
        if (node.length) {
          console.log("found by id");
          treeView.expandTo(treeView.dataItem(node));
          treeView.select(node);
        } else
          console.log("Not found by id");
      }






      window.$scope = $scope;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular">
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div class="box-col">
        <h4>Searchable TreeView</h4>
        <input data-ng-model="search" placeholder="Locate node" data-ng-change="findNode()" />
        <div id="sTree" kendo-tree-view="tree" k-data-source="treeData" k-template="itemTemplate" k-on-change="selectedItem = dataItem"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-col" ng-show="selectedItem">
        <h4>Selected: {{selectedItem.text}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="box-col">
        <h4><input data-ng-model="searchId"  placeholder="ID"  /><button ng-click="findById()">Find </h4>
        <h4><input data-ng-model="searchId2"  placeholder="Extenal ID" /><button ng-click="findByExternalId()">Find </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <style scoped>
      .k-treeview .k-in {
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```